# Transfering Repo Ownership (Github)

Tags: github

Does anyone have a reference or instructions to transfer ownership of a repo from one github account to another?

I found this...

```
https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/transferring-a-repository
```

However, it's out of date, as there is no "danger zone".

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Go to the repo you want to transfer ownership for => go to the settings of the repo => click on options on the left nav-bar => scroll down to a section with red outline [danger zone]

Comment: Thank you, I did not scroll down far enough!